# XSLT 2.0 | Modify child-node of node which was duplicated x times

Tags: xml, xslt

Im trying to copy the "product" node x times. X is the amount of value-nodes defined in the child-node "custom-attribute" with the attribute (name="ProductUnit"). So far i was able to archive that but now i want to change the node "sku" of every duplicated "product" node with a suffix.

The suffix should add the value from the "product-units" (603890001_ST 603890001_PK;20 and so on )

Here iam running into my issue because i only want to apply this sku changes to my copied "products" and not in gerneral as there may be product nodes which dont have a "custom-attribute" with the attribute (name="ProductUnit") and therefore are only copied 1:1, in addition the values may also change.

This is my code so far: http://xsltransform.net/eixk6RM/3

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enfinity xmlns="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/xcs/impex" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:ns1="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/xcs/impex" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt" major="6" minor="1" branch="enterprise" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/xcs/impex catalog.xsd http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt dt.xsd" build="build" family="enfinity">
    <product sku="603890001" import-mode="REPLACE">
        <sku>603890001</sku>
        <name xml:lang="de-AT">TEST</name>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute name="Farbe" dt:dt="string">gelb</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute name="ProductUnits" dt:dt="string">
                <value>ST</value>
                <value>PG;20</value>
                <value>KA;10</value>
            </custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>
    </product>
    <product sku="12345" import-mode="REPLACE">
        <sku>12345</sku>
        <name xml:lang="de-AT">TEST</name>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute name="Farbe" dt:dt="string">gelb</custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>
    </product>
</enfinity>
```

Output XML (right now):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><enfinity xmlns="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/xcs/impex" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:ns1="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/xcs/impex" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt" major="6" minor="1" branch="enterprise" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/xcs/impex catalog.xsd http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt dt.xsd" build="build" family="enfinity">
    <product sku="603890001" import-mode="REPLACE">
        <sku>603890001</sku>
        <name xml:lang="de-AT">TEST</name>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute name="Farbe" dt:dt="string">gelb</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute name="ProductUnits" dt:dt="string">
                <value>ST</value>
                <value>PG;20</value>
                <value>KA;10</value>
            </custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>
    </product><product sku="603890001" import-mode="REPLACE">
        <sku>603890001</sku>
        <name xml:lang="de-AT">TEST</name>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute name="Farbe" dt:dt="string">gelb</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute name="ProductUnits" dt:dt="string">
                <value>ST</value>
                <value>PG;20</value>
                <value>KA;10</value>
            </custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>
    </product><product sku="603890001" import-mode="REPLACE">
        <sku>603890001</sku>
        <name xml:lang="de-AT">TEST</name>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute name="Farbe" dt:dt="string">gelb</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute name="ProductUnits" dt:dt="string">
                <value>ST</value>
                <value>PG;20</value>
                <value>KA;10</value>
            </custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>
    </product>
    <product sku="12345" import-mode="REPLACE">
        <sku>12345</sku>
        <name xml:lang="de-AT">TEST</name>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute name="Farbe" dt:dt="string">gelb</custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>
    </product>
</enfinity>
```

Output XML (wanted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><enfinity xmlns="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/xcs/impex" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:ns1="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/xcs/impex" xmlns:dt="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt" major="6" minor="1" branch="enterprise" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/xcs/impex catalog.xsd http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/6.5/core/impex-dt dt.xsd" build="build" family="enfinity">
<product sku="603890001_ST" import-mode="REPLACE">
    <sku>603890001</sku>
    <name xml:lang="de-AT">TEST</name>
    <custom-attributes>
        <custom-attribute name="Farbe" dt:dt="string">gelb</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute name="ProductUnits" dt:dt="string">
            <value>ST</value>
            <value>PG;20</value>
            <value>KA;10</value>
        </custom-attribute>
    </custom-attributes>
</product><product sku="603890001_PG;20" import-mode="REPLACE">
    <sku>603890001</sku>
    <name xml:lang="de-AT">TEST</name>
    <custom-attributes>
        <custom-attribute name="Farbe" dt:dt="string">gelb</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute name="ProductUnits" dt:dt="string">
            <value>ST</value>
            <value>PG;20</value>
            <value>KA;10</value>
        </custom-attribute>
    </custom-attributes>
</product><product sku="603890001_KA;10" import-mode="REPLACE">
    <sku>603890001</sku>
    <name xml:lang="de-AT">TEST</name>
    <custom-attributes>
        <custom-attribute name="Farbe" dt:dt="string">gelb</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute name="ProductUnits" dt:dt="string">
            <value>ST</value>
            <value>PG;20</value>
            <value>KA;10</value>
        </custom-attribute>
    </custom-attributes>
</product>
<product sku="12345" import-mode="REPLACE">
    <sku>12345</sku>
    <name xml:lang="de-AT">TEST</name>
    <custom-attributes>
        <custom-attribute name="Farbe" dt:dt="string">gelb</custom-attribute>
    </custom-attributes>
</product>
```

Comment: Consider to cut samples to show the relevant data and also to include your XSLT in the question.

Comment: @MartinHonnen im sorry i forget the xslt i will try to cut the testdata also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should do what you want - but I am not going to compare 143 lines of codes to make sure:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.intershop.com/xml/ns/enfinity/7.1/xcs/impex">

<!-- identity transform (for all modes) -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="product[custom-attributes/custom-attribute/@name='ProductUnits']">
    <xsl:for-each select="custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@name='ProductUnits']/value">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::product" mode="multi">
            <xsl:with-param name="unit" tunnel="yes" select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sku" mode="multi">
    <xsl:param name="unit" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$unit"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks this does exactly what i want and sorry once again for the huge testdata ..... was too slow cutting it.